# Why get fade effect via shake?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have this codes:

http://jsfiddle.net/yF9bB/1/

Everything is working. But when click a button, have a shake a few second. How can i solve this?

Comment: I don't understand the question, it fades in/out fine for me.

Comment: Yes, working but please attention, click button for open tabs, get lenght long, after solved.

Comment: Is this in IE, FireFox or Chrome or what...?

Comment: @user1213807 What? Should I call a exorcist?

Comment: I still don't understand.. mind posting a screenshot of the behavior?

Comment: I can see it. Using firefox 12. When he clicks the title for the second time, when the rest of the elements are fading in, they sort of extend for a second, separating from one another before going back to their normal position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the easing type seems to solved the issue. Try like below,

```
$('caption').click(function() {        
    $(this).nextAll().toggle('fade');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/yF9bB/6/

Answer (score 0):

In IE9 only the table seems to increase in height (shake) for a second before fading out. I would assume this is an IE bug as  other browser seem to toggle the table correctly.